# The layout view '~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml' could not be located

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

The below image shows the project structure I am working on:

[image]

Inside Areas -> Billing -> Views -> _viewstart.cshtml, I have specified the path to the layout which I want to apply to the entire application but I keep getting the following error:

- **Error:**

InvalidOperationException: The layout view '~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml' could not be located. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

- **Layout Path**

  @{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to my issue, by moving the layout to the root folder as shown in the below image:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Check this:

1. Go to _Layout.cshtml properties
2. Build action must be equal to
   Content

Answer (score 0):

missing
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).